# Правильно ли будет использовать generic type для сокращения описания типов?

Tags: javascript, typescript, styled-components

Есть объект с описанием цветов для styled-components. Его нужно типизировать. Какой из вариантов по вашему мнению более корректный и читабельный?

```
export type PageColorTypes = {
  header: {
    background: string;
    shadow: string;
    mainInfo: {
      color: string;
      something: {
        color: string;
        date: string;
      };
    };
    body: {
      color: string;
      link: string;
      something: {
        color: string;
      };
    };
  };
};
```

или же

```
export type PageColorTypes<T = string> = {
  header: {
    background: T;
    shadow: T;
    mainInfo: {
      color: T;
      something: {
        color: T;
        date: T;
      };
    };
    body: {
      color: T;
      link: T;
      something: {
        color: T;
      };
    };
  };
};
```

Полей в объекте может быть больше или меньше, **суть generic type здесь скорее для сокращения описания полей**. Они всегда будут одним типом.

**Такая типизация нужна для цветов светлой/темной темы в styled-components.**

Если у вас есть свои варианты, предлагайте, очень интересно мнение со стороны =)

Comment: И что будет означать `background: number`?

Comment: Вот именно что там будут строковые значения. Типы нужны для типизации цветов для светлой/темной темы.

Comment: Вопрос возник из за того что мнения с коллегой расходятся. Он настаивает на варианте когда прописывается строковый тип для каждого поля. Но когда таких типов много, мне не нравится в целом  как это выглядит.

Comment: Если там бывает только строка, то оставьте `string` и не плодите сущности